# crear fecha en php

Tags: php

tengo un problema creando unas fecha en php. 
La situacion consiste en crear una fecha con el argumento 'first day of feb'. Si la fecha actual es marzo 30, la fecha que crea es primero de marzo, si la fecha actual es marzo 25 crea satisfactoriamente la fecha ( 1ro de febrero ). 
Pienso que debe ser alguna configuracion del server pero no me doy cuenta. 
Si alguien pudiera darme alguna idea.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo cambias la fecha del servidor? Recuerda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos el codigo que usas para crear la fecha? mira por favor [ask]

Comment: @David el codigo que agregaste esta en la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Eres el mismo usuario que [este, llamado David](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/119615/david)?. Él editó la pregunta como si fueras tú. Conviene que tengas un solo usuario. Si tienes problemas de credenciales y usuarios duplicados dilo y un moderador te puede ayudar a unir cuentas.

Comment: No es el mismo. Ya lo estamos hablando en el chat